# Handling csrf security when using fetch API to send a POST request

Tags: javascript, service-worker, web-notifications

I'm implementing web notifications for a Django/Python web app.

One of the requirements is to log the act of "receiving notification" by the target user.

To log this metric, I'm using the fetch API like so:

```
function log_notif_reception(status_code) {

  fetch('/1-on-1/push-notif/received/', {
    "method": 'POST',
    "headers": {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type':'application/json'
    },
    "credentials": 'include',
    "body": JSON.stringify({'status_code':status_code})

  })
  .then(function(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Bad status code from server.');
    }
  });

}
```

That's straight forward enough.

The problem is that the `view` on the serverside that's on the receiving end of this POST request expects a `csrf token` to ensure it's not a `Cross-Site Request Forgery` attack.

However, there's no `document` object from where I can extract a csrf token in this sceario. The user receiving the notification probably won't have the web app open. Ergo, I can't run something like the following:

```
function get_cookie(name) {
  if (!name) { return null; }
  var value = "; " + document.cookie;
  var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
  if (parts.length >= 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}
```

To circumvent this, I've had to make the server-side view `csrf_exempt`. I feel that's not very secure.

So I wanted to ask the experts how they would handle the security aspects of a scenario such as this?

Btw, serverside dev here who's had to dabble in JS and is out of his depth. Apologies for the noob question (if it is).

Comment: Disabling CSRF protection makes the site "less secure" in a way, yes. But I don't see how anyone could cause any harm here. I guess no one can do anything malicious through your api endpoint. The question is still very good! Do you have a notification id or smth available in the client? Only handle POSTs at the api when the id is provided?

Comment: @pate: I suppose that's doable - generating a unique notification ID that's passed to the server from the client (and is expected by the server).

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to obtain the csrf.
assuming you are using different domains to host the front end and the backend.
make sure you installed cors and did the setup (the setup is in the website).

you have to visit settings.py in django and add the following

> settings.py

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ['http://localhost:3000']
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:3000']
```

after that you obtain the csrf from a dedicated view in django. So in your

> views.py

```
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token

def gettoken(request):
return JsonResponse({'crsftoken': get_token(request)})
```

Then you add the url path. in the

> urls.py

```
path('/gettoken' , views.py , name = 'gettoken')
```

and by doing that you are done with your server side. after that you do an api from the front end and it returns a csrftoken which then you have to include it in all the headers where you send a post request requiring the csrf.